# Replace terms introduced by TinyMCE when the text is viewed

Tags: python, django, replace, tinymce

I am designing a digital book in Django. I have a glossary of terms, the writers write the pages of the book using TinyMCE and when the readers view this page I want the glossary in this text appear like a link to the glossary definition.

The text I store in database is a HTML text and I only must search in the plain text an replace the 'term' with 'term' when this page is accessed.

Any ideas?

Regards and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing directly with HTML code is never a good idea, if you simply do a replace on the html text you may get into problems like this:

```
<img src="static.example.com/jinja-templating"/>
```

becoming:

```
<img src="static.example.com/<a href='/glossary?word=jinja'>jinja</a>-templating"/>
```

which is absolutely destructive. No words.

### So what can I do?

#### HTML Parser

I highly recommend learning and using an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

#### Regex

Regex is also not considered safe when dealing directly with html, however at
times it can get the job done. For your case I decided to come up with a regular
expression which *might* get it done.

```
import re

html = '<div id="term"><span style="term:10px">term</span><img src="static.example.com/term"/></div><div>the technology term is amazing</div>'
glossaried = re.sub(r'>([^<>]*)term([^<>]*)<',r'>\1<a href="/glossary?word=term">term</a>\2<', html)
print glossaried
```

```
'<div id="term"><span style="term:10px"><a href="/glossary?word=term">term</a></span><img src="static.example.com/term"/></div><div>the technology <a href="/glossary?word=term">term</a> is amazing</div>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I know the problems for replacing directly in HTML, it's just the reason because of I asked here. I'm going to check BeautifulSoup now :)

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) solves the problem :) First using find_all(text="text") and then doing a replace_with("text2"). Thank you very much!